# REST API Endpoint Naming Conventions?

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have an issue with naming endpoints in a REST api.

Let's say you have a UI on the client side and in that UI is a table with a list of files. When tapping on a file it will proceed to download that selected one from the server. Additionally there is a button that when clicked will download all the files or selected files.

So the endpoints on the API may be structured like so...

- [GET] Api/Files/{fileName}

  - Gets a single file by the file name provided in the route.
- [GET] Api/Files

  - Gets a list of the files, including: FileName, Size, Type, etc...
- [GET] Api/Files

  - Gets the files, returned as a ZIP file.

As you can see the issue is the conflict of endpoints with Api/Files. I would expect both endpoints to do what I have specified that they do. But one of them needs to change... I've thought about adding something to the end but mostly verbs come to mind. Any ideas on how the formatting could be done?

Comment: Perhaps `[GET] Api/FilesArchive` would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over the different answers and testing them out, I think the best answer is just having a different endpoint name. So I've now gone for...

- [GET] Api/Files/{fileName}

  - Gets a single file by the file name provided in the route.
- [GET] Api/Files

  - Gets a list of the files, including: FileName, Size, Type, etc...
- [GET] Api/Files/Archive

  - Gets the files, returned as a ZIP file.

It's not perfect, but it makes sense.

An alternative could be...

- [GET] Api/Files/Zip
  But I think this doesn't work very well. As endpoints should never change and I may want to change it from a zip at some point...

Comment: Is this correct? Doesn't Files/{fileName} collide with Files/Archive? Archive can be taken as an id.

Comment: Files/Archive would be for getting many files downloaded as a zip, where query parameters could be specified, for example `Files/Archive?createdFrom=2022-10-20`  which will return all files created after 20th october. Whereas Files/{fileName} would be for downloading a single file based on the name of it.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean but how do you differentiate that `Archive` from `Api/Files/Archive` is not a dynamic `{filename}`?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP/RESTy way is to specify the response type you want with the [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header. The endpoint can return the results as JSON if `Accept` is `application/json` and a ZIP file if it's `application/zip`

In the worst case, you can inspect a request's `Accept` header and return either a JSON result or create a ZIP file and return it with `return File(...)`.

The [Produces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#specify-a-format) attribute can be used to specify the content type returned by each action, allowing you to write different actions for each content type.

Another option is to create a [custom output formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and have ASP.NET itself handle the generation of the ZIP file when the `Accept` header requests it. [This blog post](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2018/09/05/writing-a-custom-outputformatter-to-return-an-excel-xlsx-from-an-action-in-asp-net-core-api/) shows how to create an Excel Output formatter which returns a List of items as an Excel file when the `Accept` header requests this

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect both endpoints to do what I have specified that they do. But one of them needs to change...

Right - expanding on that idea, you have three *resources* (the contents of the file, the list of available files, the downloadable archive of files), but only two *names*; so you need at least one more name.

Good news: REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, so you don't actually need a *good* name.

```
/Api/0d660ac6-d067-42c1-b23b-daaaf946efc0
```

That will work just *fine*.  The machines don't care.

Human beings do care though; it will be a lot easier to review an access log, or find things in documentation, if we aren't trying to guess what the different UUIDs mean.

> mostly verbs come to mind

Verbs are *fine*.  Notice that these URI all work exactly like you would expect:

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post

> The HTTP/RESTy way is to specify the response type you want with the Accept header.

Probably not what you want, here.  The effective target uri is the primary cache key; when we [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) a cached entry, all of the representations will be invalidated.  If that's not the relationship you want between your list of files and your downloadable zip, then having them share a resource identifier is going to be unhappy.

`Accept` makes more sense when you have multiple representations of the same thing (ie, the list of files, but represented as HTML, JSON, text, XML, etc).

You might also consider what these identifiers look like in the access logs; should the list of files and the zip be logged using the same URI?  Do you want general purpose log parsing tools (like alarm systems) to consider the two different kinds of fetch to be equivalent?